# Adding HTML elements to Wordpress child theme

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

I am about to get started on customizing an existing Wordpress theme to meet my needs. This will be my first attempt at this, so I've been researching like crazy before getting started. Here's my question.

I know to set up a child theme within my parent theme before changing any content (and to only change things in the child theme). This seems to be pretty straightforward for CSS and JS functionality, but it seems shaky on adding HTML elements. My purpose in doing a child theme is in order to have the theme be updated without losing all of my code. Because of this, something like creating a new header.php file seems to not solve any issues, although it may temporarily give me the results I need.

If my main concern is being able to install theme updates without having to rewrite the code, then what is the best way to execute this, if at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change more than just the stylesheet, your child theme can override any file in the parent theme. To do it, simply include a file of the same name in the child theme directory, and it will override the equivalent file in the parent theme directory when your site loads.

For instance, if you want to change the PHP code for the site header, you can include a *header.php* in your child theme's directory, and that file will be used instead of the parent theme's *header.php*. A common way of doing this is making a direct copy of the parent theme file into the child theme directory. To answer your question: **this will not be overwritten during an update of the parent theme.**

You can also include files in the child theme that are not included in the parent theme. For instance, you might want to create a more specific template than is found in your parent theme, such as a template for a specific page or category archive.

See the [Codex on Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for more info.